# How to make SQL query inner join when tables are connected by a bridge table?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have create many to many relationships using code first entity framework.

Here the tables generated in DB:
[image]

I want to make sql query inner join Students on the Courses,but I don't know how to implement it in this case when bridge table between them.

How can I make sql query inner join Students on the Courses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Select c.CourseId,c.CourseName,sc.StudentId,s.StudentName 
from Courses c Inner Join StudentCourses sc On c.CourseId = sc.Course_CourseId
Inner Join Student s ON sc.Student_StudentId = s.StudentId
```